# What force is needed to put an object 200m into the air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

How much force (is that the word I am looking for?) is needed to put a 60kg weight 200m into the air using a lever? Essentially flinging the weight into the air, eg someone throwing a ball into the air with a straight arm with the arm starting at their side, pointing down and then throwing the ball upwards.

The constraints are,

1. The lever is 100cm, pivoting on a stationary pivot point
2. Weight of the object is 60kg
3. how much acceleration is needed?
4. how much force is needed?

This is not an assignment for school (left school 30 years ago), nor is it for work, it is just a plain curiosity question. If I have left an important item needed for the calculation please let me know.

Comment: The lever length isn't useful here unless you know also the *position* of the pivoting point along the lever.

Comment: This might help you estimate the advantage of a lever of a given length: http://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/levers/page_levers_1.htm

Comment: @Gert - the length surely *is* needed to calculate the force.

Comment: @LubošMotl: sure but by 'lever' I understand something like the arms of a balance or seesaw.

Comment: Gert: excellent, you better should, for a human arm,it's too much to ask. ;-)

Comment: Ah yes. 'straight arm'. Must learn to read one fine day. ;-)

Comment: @Gert. I can't seem to reproduce the answer. Is this correct `F = (60 x 9.8 x 200) / (3.1415 / 2 x 1)`  , b/c this gives me a totally different answer. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The 90-degree arc that the end of the arm makes has the length $L = \pi/2$ times 100 centimeters. If one is allowed to act with the same force $F$ on this arc, he deposits the energy $E=F\cdot L$ to the weight.

The energy he deposits must be equal to the potential energy of the weight at 200 meters,
$$ E_{200} = mgh $$
So the equation is
$$ FL = mgh$$
or 
$$ F = \frac{mgh}{L} = \frac{60\ kg\times 9.8\ m/s^2\times 200\ m}{\pi/2 \cdot 1\ m} $$
in the SI unit. Unless I have made a mistake, it is about 75,000 newtons. It's the same force as needed to lift some 7.5 tons. I am pretty sure that no human can exert this force.

I think that one could actually reduce this force almost by a factor of two if he didn't throw the object when the arm is horizontal – but he continued up to the moment when the arm is almost vertical. $\pi/2 \times R$ would be replaced by $\pi R$ and the object would be thrown along a non-vertical trajectory but that doesn't matter, it could still reach the height of 200 meters.

One may reduce the force further, by a factor of $N$, if one allows the arm to rotate $N$ times around the axis. In this way, the speed of the arm may be continuously accelerated, even with a much smaller force. Clearly, the force needed to lift the 60 kg object is the bare minimum for this exercise.

Let me also mention that the speed that the object must reach before it leaves the arm is easily calculable to be $v = \sqrt{2gh} \approx \sqrt{4,000}$ which is about 63 meters per second. Even with the many rotations of the arm, it's a pretty high speed. The circumference of the arm of radius 1 meter is 6.28 meters, so 63 meters per second means the final frequency of 10 rotations of the arm per second. A very fast exercise, indeed.

Comment: I would imagine not. Thanks so much for the help. Sorry to be a pest, but what does `mgh` stand for? And thanks for the additional scenarios.

Comment: $mgh$ is $m\cdot g\cdot h$, the product of the mass $m$, the gravitational acceleration $g=9.8$ meters per second per second, and the height $h$ equal to 200 meters.

Comment: BTW, it was intended for a single half revolution type setup. I wanted to know how much force and acceleration was needed to get such a heavy object in a very short distance.

Comment: *"I wanted to know how much force and acceleration was needed to get such a heavy object in a very short distance."* Far too much for even a Olympian athlete! :-)

Comment: @Gert, I would even go so far to say that if that much force was possible, it probably rip your arm off?

Comment: Well, you'd rip the muscles from the bone and probably dislocate the shoulder. You'd definitely be sore the next day.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the answer. Is this correct `F = (60 x 9.8 x 200) /  (3.1415 / 2  x 1)` , b/c this gives me a totally different answer. Cheers

Comment: Which totally different answer? A gummi bear?

Comment: @KyloRen I plugged what you wrote verbatim into WolframAlpha and the result was 74,868 which is approximately 75,000. What answer did you get?

Comment: @pentane, of crap, I am so stupid sometimes. Here I was trying to get the answer to equal 25,000, b/c that is what I thought Luboš Motl answer was. I was also getting 75,000. Thanks for waking me up.